# Invalid Json data return page content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I call a controller action using jquery ajax (see the below code), After the action has been executed, An Invalid Json error was raised. And I've notice that, it returns the page content. Why did it happen. can Anyone help me to solve this problem?

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
       public ActionResult ViewDetails(int id)
       {
           var eventsdetails = _service.GeteventByID(id);
           return View("EventDetails",eventsdetails);
       }


       [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult UpdateAnswers(string answers, string question, string controlid, int eventid)
       {
           var replacetext=string.Empty;
           if (answers.Length>0) 
             replacetext = answers.Replace("\n", ",");
           _service.UpdateAnswers(eventid, replacetext, controlid);
          return RedirectToAction("ViewDetails", new { id = eventid });
       }
```

Javascript

```
function dropdownlist(controlid, title, answers, eventid) {
            var $answersreplaced = answers.replace( /\,/g , "&nbsp;\r");
            var $deleteDialog = $('<div><textarea id="answerlist"  rows="10" cols="50">' + $answersreplaced + '</textarea><div><div style="font-size:9px">(To change back to an open answer field, delete all choices above and save)</div>');
            $deleteDialog.dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 280,
                width: 350,
                title: title + " - Edit Choices",
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Save": function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateAnswers")',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: { answers: $('#answerlist').val(),
                                question: title,
                                controlid: controlid,
                                eventid: eventid
                            },
                            success: function (result) {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                                alert(result);
                            },
                            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                alert(thrownError);
                                // alert('there was a problem saving the new answers, please try again');
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're not returning a JsonResult from the action, you're redirecting to another action, which in turn returns a ViewResult.

Try something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateAnswers(string answers, string question, string controlid, int eventid)
{
    var replacetext=string.Empty;
    if (answers.Length>0) 
        replacetext = answers.Replace("\n", ",");
    _service.UpdateAnswers(eventid, replacetext, controlid);
    var eventsdetails = _service.GeteventByID(eventid);
    return Json(eventdetails);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I returning a JasonResult, I encounter an Internal Server error, from this I don't know how to figure it out, since the error is very specific. Any ideas?

Comment: Use Google Chrome and view the Console / Network tab, it should explain the error in more detail

Answer (score 0):

You specify `dataType: 'json'` in your AJAX request and inside your `UpdateAnswers` controller action you `return RedirectToAction` which obviously redirects to the ViewDetails action which in turn returns a view which in turn is HTML. So this doesn't make sense.

You have to return Json from the UpdateAnswers controller action instead of redirecting.

Comment: Thank you, but when I returning a JasonResult, I encounter an Internal Server error, from this I don't know how to figure it out, since the error is very specific. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, look with FireBug at the AJAX request to see the details about the error message. You should really learn to debug your code. You might also try putting breakpoints in the controller action and see if it is hit.